# Getting an error while connecting to postgres running in Docker: pq: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: postgresql, docker, go, sqlx

Trying to open Database but it is saying password authentication failed for user "postgres"
I am not able to find the root cause of this problem.First time,i am using Docker. Pleas help

```
func openDB() (*sqlx.DB, error) {
    q := url.Values{}
    q.Set("sslmode", "disable")
    q.Set("timezone", "utc")

    u := url.URL{
        Scheme:   "postgres",
        User:     url.UserPassword("postgres", "postgres"),
        Host:     "localhost",
        Path:     "postgres",
        RawQuery: q.Encode(),
    }
    fmt.Println(u.String())
    
    // fmt.Println(u.String()) is
    // postgre://postgres:postgres@localhost/postgres?sslmode=disable&timezone=utc
    return sqlx.Open("postgres", u.String())
}
```

**docker-compose.yaml** looks like this.

```
version: '3'
networks:
  shared-network:
    driver: bridge
services:
  db:
    container_name: sales_db
    networks:
      - shared-network
    image: postgres:11.1-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

Comment: "password authentication failed" means your username or password are wrong, or your server is configured not to allow password authentication. We can't help with that.

Comment: @Flimzy  If it were not configured to use password authentication, you would not get that message.  But you can get it if you need a password, but one has not been set.

Comment: Look in the database server's log file for a more complete error report.

Comment: There was a port issue.It's working after changing the port. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There was no problem in code. I changed the port eveything is working now.

```
func openDB() (*sqlx.DB, error) {
    q := url.Values{}
    q.Set("sslmode", "disable")
    q.Set("timezone", "utc")

    u := url.URL{
        Scheme:   "postgres",
        User:     url.UserPassword("postgres", "postgres"),
        Host:     "localhost:5433", // change here
        Path:     "postgres",
        RawQuery: q.Encode(),
    }
    fmt.Println(u.String())
    
    // fmt.Println(u.String()) is
    // postgre://postgres:postgres@localhost/postgres?sslmode=disable&timezone=utc
    return sqlx.Open("postgres", u.String())
}
```

**and**

```
version: '3'
networks:
  shared-network:
    driver: bridge
services:
  db:
    container_name: sales_db
    networks:
      - shared-network
    image: postgres:11.1-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    ports:
      - 5433:5432 //change here
```