# Authentication error while connecting to Postgres DB with diesel-cli

Tags: postgresql, docker, rust, docker-compose, rust-diesel

I'm getting `connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "username"` error when running `diesel setup` command.

I use `docker-compose` for DB setup. Here is the content of my `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: "to-do-postgres"
    image: 'postgres:11.2'
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=username
      - POSTGRES_DB=to_do_db
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
```

Here is the content of my `.env` file:

`DATABASE_URL=postgres://username:password@localhost/to_do_db`

I'm using correct credentials inside `DATABASE_URL` and still getting an error. It looks like if I use `postgres://postgres:password@localhost/to_do_db` as `DATABASE_URL` setup command runs successfully, but migrations do not seem to work.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to connect to a local PostgreSQL database running on docker with TypeORM + pgAdmin4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63366952/unable-to-connect-to-a-local-postgresql-database-running-on-docker-with-typeorm)

Comment: My case is a little different: 1. I don't use a volume, 2. It is my initial setup and I don't see a message saying that initialization script was skipped

Comment: Well in that case it's likely a duplicate of one of the other questions that show up if you search for this error message. It's a bit hard to judge as your question does not contain a [mre].

Comment: I literally posted all the code, I don't know how I can provide even more information.

Comment: Found my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62536977/getting-an-error-while-connecting-to-postgres-running-in-docker-pq-password-au. It looks like I needed to change a port mapping.